# Mint 15 on Lenovo G700: wired internet not working (Atheros QCA8172)

Tags: linux, networking, linux-mint, ethernet, internet

Mint 15 doesn't see internet after installing it in dualboot with windows 8 (in Windows internet works well). My network card is Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet (rev 10).

What I did:

1. Install drivers from http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/alx
2. Update kernel to 3.11.6

But it didn't fix the problem.

---

Here some additional information.

#### ifconfig

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:11:d8:0c:73:68  
          inet6 addr: fe80::211:d8ff:fe0c:7368/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:18 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:25 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:25 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2951 (2.9 KB)  TX bytes:2951 (2.9 KB)
```

#### interfaces

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

#### ip

```
$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:11:d8:0c:73:68 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

#### iptables

```
$ sudo iptables -L -nv

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

#### iwconfig

```
$ iwconfig

eth0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

#### lsmod

```
$ lsmod

Module                  Size  Used by
iptable_filter         12810  0 
ip_tables              27716  1 iptable_filter
x_tables               34194  2 ip_tables,iptable_filter
bnep                   23966  2 
parport_pc             32866  0 
rfcomm                 74589  0 
bluetooth             391564  10 bnep,rfcomm
ppdev                  17711  0 
binfmt_misc            17508  1 
nls_iso8859_1          12713  1 
ext2                   73792  1 
joydev                 17613  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     41736  1 
snd_hda_codec_idt      55053  1 
snd_hda_intel          53038  3 
snd_hda_codec         194727  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13613  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               107140  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         18798  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30416  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                66061  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
lpc_ich                21163  0 
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29989  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
uvcvideo               82247  0 
snd                    69657  17 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
psmouse               104064  0 
soundcore              12680  1 snd
ideapad_laptop         18596  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
sparse_keymap          13890  1 ideapad_laptop
videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         40785  1 uvcvideo
mac_hid                13253  0 
serio_raw              13413  0 
dm_multipath           27371  0 
lp                     17799  0 
mei_me                 18418  0 
scsi_dh                14873  1 dm_multipath
mei                    78448  1 mei_me
videodev              138443  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
bcma                   47065  0 
parport                42466  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
btrfs                 847481  0 
xor                    21411  1 btrfs
zlib_deflate           27110  1 btrfs
raid6_pq               97812  1 btrfs
libcrc32c              12615  1 btrfs
hid_generic            12548  0 
dm_mirror              22277  0 
usbhid                 53329  0 
dm_region_hash         20932  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 18527  2 dm_region_hash,dm_mirror
hid                   106004  2 hid_generic,usbhid
usb_storage            66567  0 
nouveau               979463  0 
i915                  682899  3 
mxm_wmi                13021  1 nouveau
video                  19574  2 i915,nouveau
i2c_algo_bit           13564  2 i915,nouveau
ttm                    84705  1 nouveau
drm_kms_helper         53178  2 i915,nouveau
alx                    32792  0 
mdio                   13807  1 alx
wmi                    19256  2 mxm_wmi,nouveau
drm                   302332  6 ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper,nouveau
ahci                   30063  6 
libahci                32088  1 ahci
```

#### lspci

```
$ lspci -v

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=06, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: d0000000-d0ffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000a0000000-00000000bfffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
    Memory at d1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 41
    Memory at d1600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    Memory at d1614000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at d1619000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at d1610000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=07, subordinate=07, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=08, subordinate=08, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: d1500000-d15fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=09, subordinate=09, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: d1400000-d14fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at d1618000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
    I/O ports at 4088 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 4094 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 4080 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 4090 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 4060 [size=32]
    Memory at d1617000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 10
    Memory at d1615000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 4040 [size=32]

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3910
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at b2000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

08:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 0611
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at d1500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge

09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3803
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    Memory at d1400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=128]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: alx
```

#### rfkill

```
$ rfkill list all

0: ideapad_3g: Wireless WAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

#### dmesg

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bz7Myw57yQvoVlZCLTNrUjdhNmc/edit?usp=sharing&pli=1

Comment: Have you tried powerdown and then boot Linux. I have had Windows hardware drivers in the past, that on a dual boot system would not be replaced/reset with a soft reboot and block Linux functionality.

Comment: Also please include the output from the `dmesg` command, there is likely an error message in there if something went wrong with loading the driver for this network card. Or perhaps it's not being detected at all?

Comment: @Anthon, powerdown not help me.

Comment: Press `Fn` + `F2` to turn WiFi on, it's quite common that that's the problem.

Comment: @slm, all dmesg output here http://ideone.com/5o3WRf

Comment: @slm, network card is detected, but cannot connect to internet

Comment: @PMint, I am trying connect by ethernet, not wi-fi

Comment: @slm, here full dmesg output: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bz7Myw57yQvoVlZCLTNrUjdhNmc/edit?usp=sharing&pli=1